# Confusion about 2 names in C: escape sequence, floating point numbers

Tags: c, floating-point

I'm referring to C.
Both the textbook and wikipedia don't give a clarified answer, can anyone tell me why these two weird names?

Comment: What's weird about them? What doesn't Wikipedia answer about them?

Comment: Confusion about 2 names: firetrucks and DVD's - what are they and what's the differences?

Answer (score 4):

**Escape sequences** are sequences of characters that begin with the **escape character**, the backslash (`\`). The backslash causes the following character(s) to "escape" their normal meaning.

```
b -> \b  # Backspace
n -> \n  # Newline
0 -> \0  # NUL
x40 -> \x40  # Character code 0x40
```

**Fixed-point numbers** always have the same number of positions after the radix point, even if they are displayed with more or less. **Floating-point numbers** have a *variable* number of positions after the radix point, defined by a bitfield within the number itself.

```
Fixed point:
1.0000
12.3456

Floating point:
1.02
345.6
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there are 3 points that I don't understand. 1."...after the radix point, even if they are displayed with more or less." -- what do you mean by "more or less? 2. So "Floating point" means a "the number of digits after the radix point can change(float)"? 3.Why there are 4 digits after the radix point(1.0000, 12,3456)?

Answer (score 1):

[Floating-Point Numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point) //this is wikipedia, but the article is good and simple, don't say it doesn't help

Example:

```
1.23f
4.20 
6e-2 //same as 0.06 i.e. 6*10^-2
```

terminology: ***floating***-point (as opposed to ***fixed***-point) because the internal representation doesn't specify certain number of bits for whole part and fractional part. Thus, the point is floating.

[Escape Sequences](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

Example:

```
\n //newline
\t //tab
\r //caret return
```

Answer (score 1):

The names seem not too weird if you think at them metaphorically. An "escape sequence" is a sequence of character that "escapes" common rule of something. "Floating point numbers" are numbers where the point (decimal point) can "float" (referring to its position), i.e. it can be "anywhere".

Answer (score 0):

**Escape sequence** is a portion of a string containing a special character. For instance, if you need double quotes inside a string literal (remember, string literals are enclosed within double quotes), then you use the following escape sequence:

```
\"
```

Floating point numbers are arbitrary precision numbers using floating point representation (i.e., 2.56, 3.1415, you get the idea). Read about number representation somewhere, and you will learn a lot about them.